How to Automatically Extract Tooltip Values from Grafana Graphs at Specific Timestamps?
I'm working on a Grafana frontend that visualizes time series data from CAN-traces recorded from cars. The data is stored in AWS Timestream for live analytics. Our team, consisting of developers and engineers, needs a feature that allows them to extract the values of all displayed graphs at specific points in time.
Currently, Grafana allows adding annotations by clicking on the graph, but this requires manual entry of information. I'm looking for a solution to automatically extract the information shown in the tooltip when hovering over the graph.
In the tool I'm trying to replicate, there are two vertical lines that can be moved horizontally across the graph. These lines help determine the specific time points at which signal values should be displayed in a table below the graph.
Questions:

Is there a built-in way in Grafana to automatically capture tooltip values when clicking or hovering over the graph and then display them in a table?

If not, what would be the best approach to implement this functionality? Are there plugins, scripts, or custom solutions recommended for such a feature?

How can I achieve the functionality of movable vertical lines that extract and display data in a table upon selection?


Your insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
enter image description here

Annotations Feature in Grafana:

I attempted to use Grafana's built-in annotations feature, hoping it would allow me to click on the graph and automatically capture the tooltip values.



Expected Outcome:

I expected that using annotations would enable me to automatically record and display the values from tooltips without manual entry.

Actual Outcome:

With annotations, I found that all information needed to be manually entered, which was not efficient for our needs and didn't meet the automatic data capture expectation.

